# How to access WSO2 Identity Server via REST from SoapUI?

Tags: wso2, soapui, wso2-identity-server

I am accessing WSO2 endpoint `https://localhost:9443/wso2/scim/Users` from SoapUI. I am providing username **admin** and password **admin**.

But getting

```
{"Errors":[{"code":"401","description":"Authentication failed for this resource."}]}
```

Comment: This is too broad. It is difficult without out specific details of the issue.

Comment: I have found out that issue was due to WSO2 Identity server's wrong exception description. If WSO2 Identity Server has no users, authentication is failed. You must have at least one user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just adding a user in wso2 identity server resolved this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Select the “Preemptive Authentication” option in the global HTTP Preferences in the SoapUI.

Comment: Later I used google chrome's extension **Postman**, found it much better than SoapUI.